# Mapping 5 columns to one (ID, dimension) table without 5 joins?

Tags: sql, inner-join, dimension, surveymonkey

I'm using survey monkey's API to dump survey data into a SQL data warehouse.

So I'm dumping response data into a table 'resonses' thusly:

```
survey_id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5

survey3944, 848948344, 430984384, 43094839, 238094983, 2380284
```

Then I have a dimensional table 'answer_key' that has the id/ text combos. Such as

```
ID, text

848948344, 5 - very satisfied
```

I'm wondering how I can join the 5 answer columns above into meaningful text (or at least the integer) without doing 5 joins.

I mean say I have the table 'responses' and the table 'answer_key'.

My initial thought would be go through the motion:

```
Select r.survey_id, a.text, a2.text, a3.text, a4.text, a5.text
from responses r
inner join answer_key a on r.q1 = a.id
inner join answer_key a2 on r.q2 = a2.id
inner join answer_key a3 on r.q3 = a3.id
inner join answer_key a4 on r.q4 = a4.id
inner join answer_key a5 on r.q5 = a5.id
```

Is that the best way to accomplish this? Just wondering. Especially if the survey is expanded to 10 questions, or what not.

I realize I can have a row for each question response rather than each survey for the table structure --- that's a possibility but I think it's a bit more difficult given the structure of the JSON, but maybe it's more logical.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following email to SurveyMonkey support

> I need to read bulk responses for survey using  $"surveys/{surveyId}
>   /responses/bulk"  , but current response
>   returns ids for questions and answers.
>
> I have separately to do question requests  $"surveys/{surveyId}/details"
>
> and join the responses.
>
> It's looks like typical scenario and most of
>   the clients do it. It will be nice if API would support denormalized
>   mode, when related information will be return in one response. I
>   understand that it will be data duplication, but it significantly
>   simplify usage of your API.

They replied that they will consider it in a future. If someone believe that it is a good  idea, let them know at api-support@surveymonkey.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do that with your DB structure, but I'm not a SQL expert. I'd suggest changing the DB structure, basic example going off yours:

`responses` Table:
SurveyID, QuestionID, ChoiceID

`answer_key` Table:
QuestionID, Text

Then do something like:

```
Select r.survey_id, a.text
from responses r
inner join answer_key a on r.QuestionID = a.QuestionID
```

I'm thinking in general it'll be a lot easier to work with if you separate each question into it's own row, rather than one table with all questions. Especially if you're going to use multiple surveys with differing number of questions, this will be more flexible.

You may want to break it down even more to `VariableID` or something in case you have multi-row questions like matrix type questions. Then you can query for exactly what you want more easily.